# bash: tee eats newlines after exec

Tags: bash, io-redirection, exec, tee

To output both stdout and stderr from a script to the console and to a log file, I’ve found a beautiful solution with tee:

```
exec &> >(tee log.file)
```

The problem is, that sometimes tee seems to be eating newlines. For example, I have a trap on exit that prints a newline and only then exits.

```
trap "echo && exit 55" EXIT HUP INT QUIT KILL
```

It makes the shell print the prompt from the new line instead of wherever user might have pressed `^C` while the script was running. And it doesn’t work, when there’s such a call to exec.

Comment: Bit confused. Could you explain how prompt getting a newline is related to tee eating newline?

Comment: @Vikyboss that’s what I would like someone to explain to me…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method redirects stderr to stdout then pipes to tee. I think it's a little more readable.

```
exec 2>&1 | tee log.file
```

I've tested this on my machine and haven't encountered the "newline eating" problem.

Comment: Does this actually write the stdout of the script to the log.file? If so, may I know your version of Bash? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`tee` is most likely being killed by the signal before receiving the newline.